# How to add a context menu entry in OS file explorer using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to know if is is possible to add an entry in the context menu (right click menu) of the OS file explorer (e.g. Windows Explorer) for my program developed with Qt.

The objective is that when I right click on a file or a directory, I'd like my element to appear in that menu and do something when the user clicks on it.

Comment: When you say "a file or directory", what are you referring to?  Are you using a QFileDialog and want to be able to right-click on the files and directories shown inside it?  Or are you talking about files and directories in the system desktop?  Or something else?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the files and directories in my OS any where in the system

Comment: Outside of your application? Adding to say Windows Explorer's right click menu? That will require writing a custom shell extension DLL (or at least adding registry entries to run a program). You'd have to do it differently for every OS (if it's even possible in a given OS). If you're talking about a list of files inside your application, that's quite different...

Comment: @darron I intend to use Mingw as a cross compiler ! does this make it harder??

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI It was a bit hard to read the question. I think I now understood it. Can you please have a look if my edit is correct? Maybe I misunderstood your objective.

Comment: I think Qt doesn't have a solution for that, as it is highly system-dependent. In Linux, it even depends on the particular file explorer application, as the user can choose from many. You had to write into configuration files for these programs to provide a universal solution to your problem. On Windows, I think it can be done quite easily (I guess the Win32 API has something for that, but Qt doesn't help you with that). This being said, adding this entry is done *outside* of your application, as it doesn't have to run when the user clicks on a file... For example in a setup program.

Comment: (Of course, you can add this entry on the first run of your application and/or from within a settings dialog. It's up to you when to add the entry. But once you told the Windows Explorer that it should show this entry (and how to react, i.e. what command to execute), you're done.)

Comment: @leemes Well the issue is that i am using Qt on an openSuse OS so i think this is going to add other difficulties to how to do it

Answer (score 5):

The context menu in Windows Explorer has nothing directly to do with Qt. By simply setting a few registry entries, you can add items to the context menu that launch an application and pass parameters, such as the selected file(s) to that application.

If you google for "Adding to Windows Context Menu" you'll find articles which explain which registry entries you need to edit. [Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) one such article

Once you've made the registry entries, you can export them as files that can be run on installation of your application.

Comment: What about other OSes like Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac?

Comment: I can't answer about Linux, but for OS X, there is no API and the simple answer is that its not possible. Realistically, this could be done with code injection into the Finder process.